# Increase the space between the dots on the pattern lock

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, root-access, themes, pattern-lock

My phone is a Motorola RAZR MAXX, the moto skin that comes with it has one feature I really like: the dots on the pattern unlock screen are very far apart. I recently installed Cyanogenmod, and found that the Pattern is now much harder to use. The dots are now far closer together, which makes it much more difficult to properly enter the unlock pattern. I also have the new Nexus 7, and I have found that it has the same problem.

Is there a way to make the pattern bigger? I do not want more dots, I want a 3x3 grid - with more space. It seems like this should be possible to achieve, since Motorola did it with their skin.

Comment: Two down votes, no comments. Is there something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to build a lock screen that is like motorola's one or find a lock screen that you like from the market, I think you are out of luck otherwise.